# Error No handler was subscribed to command when send command

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I have a Spring Boot microservice using AxonIq for Eventsourcing pattern. I have an hexagonal architecture with 3 modules :

- rest-adapter

  - MyCommandController
  - MyQueryController
- domain

  - commands

    - MyAggregate defining all CommandHandler and EventSourcingHandler
    - all commands class
    - CommandService implenent creat, update, delete and inject CommandGateway
  - queries

    - interface Projector defining all EventHandler and QueryHandler
    - all Query definition
    - QueryService implement all query and inject the QueryGateway
- infra

  - MyMongoRepository extends MongoRepository
  - MyMongoProjector implementation of Projector using @Service annotation
  - MyApplicationConfig for creation of CommandService and QueryService

When I try to post a new element in the eventstore I have this error : No handler was subscribed to command.
I haded breakpoint in the subscrib of SimpleCommandBus and SimpleQueryBus and in the bootstrap of the application only one breakpoint was activated the simpleQueryBus.

MyAggregate.java

```
package com.omb.commands;

import com.omb.events.SchedulingCreatedEvent;
import com.omb.events.SchedulingUpdatedEvent;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;

import static org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle.apply;

@Aggregate
public class MyAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public MyAggregate() {}

    @CommandHandler
    public MyAggregate(CreateMyAggregateCommand command) {
        apply(new MyAggregateCreatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getName()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(UpdateMyAggregateCommand command) {
        apply(new MyAggregateUpdatedEvent(command.getId(), command.getName()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(MyAggregateCreatedEvent event) {
        id = event.getId();
        name = event.getName();
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(MyAggregateUpdatedEvent event) {
        id = event.getId();
        name = event.getName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my probleme, I made a mistake in my @ComponentScan definition.